# Blender 2.79 install - Installer has stopped responding

Tags: windows, installation, error

I've had no problems installing earlier versions of blender. But installing the new 2.79 (Windows, x64) installer on Windows 10 ends up with the installer flashing a window, then going away. Followed minutes later by a popup that says "The installer has stopped responding".

I've tried the following:

- Turning off UAC
- Redownloading
- Running the "Program Compatibility Troubleshooter" (which disabled version check).

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Please report bugs and other issues at https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: Reported. Also hope to hear from anyone that had a similar issue, and possibly a way to work around it.

Comment: Well, you can always just download the zip version and extract it. You don't need to install Blender to use it.

Comment: Problem is solved - if there is a pending windows update, then the installer fails. If someone has the same issue, make sure all downloaded windows updates are installed and reboot before installing again.

Comment: I have the same problem with the 32 bit installer. I'm now downloading the zipped version because I don't want to update windows... I'm getting Linux next!